# Closed/open components confusion

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying point-set topology from the John B. Conway book and in the chapter about connectedness there is a result that states that the closure of a connected set is connected and each component is closed, and then right away the next result states that the components of an open set in $\mathbb R^q$ are all open, both make intuitive sense at some level but they don't make sense together, what am I missing? Or is it just the fact that connected sets are both open and closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no conflict when you realize that they’re talking about two different spaces.

For a simple example consider the open set $U=(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ in $\Bbb R$. Let $\tau$ be the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, and let $\tau_U$ be the relative (subspace) topology on $U$. The components of $U$ are $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$. These components are open both in $\tau_U$ and in $\tau$. They are also closed in $\tau_U$, but they are not closed in $\tau$. In both $\tau_U$ and $\tau$, however, their closures are connected: they are their own closures in $\tau_U$, and their closures in $\tau$ are $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$.

To sum up, a component of a set is always closed in that set, but it need not be closed in the ambient space. A component of an open set in $\Bbb R^n$ is always both open and closed in that set, and it is always open in $\Bbb R^n$, but it is closed in $\Bbb R^n$ if and only if it is all of $\Bbb R^n$.